# importing multiple columns from one sheet to new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

This is my source sheet which has different columns such as D_ID, Modules, Function_Name etc.

[image]

I would like to export few columns such as "D_ID","Function_Name","Sub_Unit_Number","length" from ActiveSheet to new worksheet.

My output worksheet should look like this:

[image]

The logic that I tried to use is first to create a new worksheet using vba code and then use the for loop to go through Range ("A1: K1") to find if each cell value in this range matches with the string "D_ID" , "Function_Name","Sub_Unit_Number","length". If yes, then I need to write in new worksheet.

But my logic is getting failed.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me with different logic or code to get it work.

```
         Sub CreateNewSheet()
         Dim rep As Integer
         Dim sheet_name_to_create As String

         sheet_name_to_create = "Test_Sheet"

         'a statement to go through other worksheets
         For rep = 1 To (Worksheets.Count)

          'search the sheet wth the name if that exists
         If LCase(Sheets(rep).Name) = LCase(sheet_name_to_create) Then
           MsgBox "This sheet already exists"
         Exit Sub
         End If

         Next

           Sheets.Add After:=Sheets("Original_Sheet")
           Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Name = sheet_name_to_create

           End Sub

          Sub Extract_data()
           ' this sub routine extracts D_ID, Function_Name, Sub_Unit_Number                  
            'and Length from the Original_Sheet
          Dim LastColumn As Integer
          Dim cell As Range
          Dim sht As Worksheet
          Dim data As String


         Set sht = Worksheets("Original_Sheet")
         LastColumn = sht.Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

         For Each cell In sht.Range("A1:K" & LastColumn).Cells

         data = cell.Value
          If data = "D_ID" Then
            ' I need to import to the new worksheet

          ElseIf data = "Function_Name" Then
             ' I need to import to the new worksheet

          ElseIf data = "Sub_Unit_Number" Then
              ' I need to import to the new worksheet

          ElseIf data = "Length" Then
                ' I need to import to the new worksheet

          End If
          End Sub


          Sub MyNewProcedure()
          Call CreateNewSheet
          Call Extract_data
          End Sub
```

Comment: Submit the code you've written so far.

Comment: @nilsman i have added code, but it is not completely correct as i am using vba now for this task and i am not familiar with syntax and all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what the problem is but i give it try. The code you got works perfectly, just one or two mistakes in there.

```
LastColumn = sht.Cells(1, ->here<-.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

The .Columns need a object, here it would be sht.Columns.count

```
Next cell
```

Is missing under the last End If so the for-loop got an next

Then you just need to the name different sheets write at this points:

```
 Set sht = Worksheets("Orignal Sheet")
```

And then you need to put a copy command in the If body that reference the current column like this:

```
 data = cell.Value
      If data = "D_ID" Then
        MsgBox ("Got it")
        Sheets("Table3").Columns(cell.Columns).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Table4").Columns(2)
```